# MKDIRP does have a permission to create new folder, how to give the permission?

Tags: node.js, mkdir

I installed mkdirp to create new folder when the folder is not existed.

(Using **npm install -g mkdirp**)

But it seems like the mkdirp doesn't have the permission to create new folder,

when I try, I got this error,

```
{ [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/upload'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/upload' }
```

This is my code, and I'm using MAC

```
'fileUpload' : function(req, res, next){
    var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
    mkdirp('/upload/image', function (err) {
        if (err) console.error(err)
            console.log ('!');
    });
```

How can I give the permisson to mkdirp to create new folder?

Comment: what it says is that the user running the node code cannot write to /.  So far as i can tell, it's not a mkdirp issue but a UNIX one.  Give your user the proper rights or choose another destination.  Usuallly, only the super user can write to /

Comment: @tgo Yes, it was pointing /(Root), After I changed to right directory, it works fine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As tgo said,

It was pointing system / (root) directory, after I changed to right (web) sub-directory, it works fine.

Answer (score -2):

Have you provided '777' for all your file directories ? This should give permission to create and execute files.